# Java - Generics - Casting generic object in generic specified object doesn't work

Tags: java, generics, methods, generic-programming, generic-method

I'm trying to resolve this apparently simple generic casting problem :

First, declaring this simple generic object :

```
public interface GenericObject<T> {}
```

Second, declaring this working interface :

```
public interface Generic { // I don't want to do Generic<T>

    <T> void setGenericObject(GenericObject<T> obj);

}
```

Then, let's implements this interface :

```
public class GenericImpl implements Generic {

    private GenericObject<String> genericObject; // This is needed

    @Override
    public <String> void setGenericObject(GenericObject<String> obj) {
        genericObject = obj; // eclipse give me this error :
                             // Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
                             // interfaces.GenericObject<String> to
                             // interfaces.GenericObject<java.lang.String>
    }

}
```

How can I solve this error ?

Edit :

Actualy, the only way I have to solve this issue is to do this :

```
public class GenericImpl implements Generic {

    private GenericObject<String> genericObject; 

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // I don't realy like this
    @Override
    public <T> void setGenericObject(GenericObject<T> obj) {
        genericObject = (GenericObject<String>) obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). `<String> void` is not doing what you think it's doing. You're defining a new generic type parameter using the identifier "String". It may as well say `<FooBar> void`. You should remove it. Only problem is that when you do, the method is not correctly overriding the method from the interface

Comment: The problem is that `Generic` specifies that any implementers should be able to implement `setGenericObject` for *all* values of `T`. Your implementation only works for strings, so it is not fulfilling the contract as defined by the interface. The best way to achieve what you want is to have `Generic<T>` and `GenericImpl implements Generic<String>` but you said you don't want to do that

Comment: plaese see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433279/is-it-possible-to-have-an-interface-method-defined-with-a-generic-return-type-an

Comment: Ok. @Michael Do you think there are any way to solve my problem without doing `@SuppressWarning` ?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that

```
public <String> void setGenericObject(GenericObject<String> obj)
```

where the `String` has nothing to do with the your intended `java.lang.String`. Here the `String` is just a type parameter whose name is `String` by accident.

Please refer to [Is it possible to have an interface method defined with a generic return type and a concrete implementation define the return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433279/is-it-possible-to-have-an-interface-method-defined-with-a-generic-return-type-an).

Comment: Ok, I understand that my `<String>` tag is like `<T>`, but what do you propose to solve my problem ? And keep in mind that I don't want to do `Generic<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

If `T` is not used in `Generic`, then just use a wildcard.

```
class Generic {
    List<?> list;
    void set(List<?> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    int size() {
        return list.size(); // doesn't care about T
    }
}
```

---

Case 2:

If `T` is only used as **local variables**, then declare `<T>` on the method

```
class Generic {
    <T> void swapFirstAndSecond(List<T> list) {
        T first = list.get(0), second = list.get(1);
        list.set(1, first);
        list.set(0, second);
    }
}
```

---

Case 3:

If several **fields** and **methods** use the same type `T`, but the exact type of `T` is not important, then delacre `<T>` on the class

```
class Generic<T> {
    List<T> list;
    void set(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    T getFirst() {
        return list.get(0);
    }
}
```

---

Case 4:

If `T` must be a specific type, like `String`, then don't declare type parameter `<T>`

```
class Generic {
    List<String> list;
    void set(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    boolean isFirstContainsSecond() {
        String first = list.get(0), second = list.get(1);
        // call String.contains here, so T must be String
        return first.contains(second);
    }
}
```