# Can a class abstract class have a atribute that is a interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I am working with the DAO pattern on Java, for the implementation I use a DAO interface that is implemented by a "ItemDAO" abstracted class witch then leads to classes like "ItemDAOTxt" and "ItemDAOXml". This same logic is used on classes like "OrderDAO" and "EmployeesDAO; I am working on a abstract class that will use a DAO in a particular way, "ClassA". So is there a way to make some different classes extends "ClassA" in a way that I can use any DAO I want?

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
    private DAO<T> dao;
    //...
}
```

Comment: What is `T`? Perhaps you meant `public abstract class ClassA<T>`, so the subclass can specify what `T` is, e.g. `public class SubA extends ClassA<Foo>`?

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433279/is-it-possible-to-have-an-interface-method-defined-with-a-generic-return-type-an

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    T getValue();
}
abstract class Bar<T,U> implements Foo<T> {
    Bar(T t,U u) {
        this.t=t;
        this.u=u;
    }
    @Override public T getValue() {
        return t;
    }
    T t;
    U u;
}
class Baz<T,U>extends Bar<T,U> {
    Baz(T t,U u) {
        super(t,u);
    }
}
public class So56811426 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Baz<Integer,Character> baz=new Baz<Integer,Character>(42,'x');
        System.out.println(baz.getValue()+" "+baz.u);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I am actually doing with my DAO classes. But I want to make an abstract class be able to use any "Baz" type classes.

Comment: what do you mean by use any baz type? hold a reference to a Baz<T,U>? or ?