# Generic method difference between Int32 and int

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have problem with understanding generic method in interface. I'm using .NET framework 4.8 with auto C# version so it should be C# 7.3. Example below

Interface is:

```
public interface IRegister
{
  Nullable<T> Read<T>() where T: struct;
  void Write<T>(T value) where T : struct;
}
```

Now some class inherit from interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractRegister : IRegister
{
  protected ModbusClient client;
  protected int Address;
  public abstract Nullable<T> Read<T>() where T : struct;
  public virtual void Write<T>(T value) where T : struct
  {
    return;
  }
  public AbstractRegister(int address, ModbusClient client)
  {
    this.client = client;
    this.Address = address;
  }
}
```

Now I have some class inherited from AbstractRegister:

```
class InputRegister_int : AbstractRegister
{
  public InputRegister_int(int address, ModbusClient client) : base(address, client) { }

  public override int? Read<int>()
  {
    if (client == null)
      return null;
    return this.client.ReadInputRegisters(this.Address, 1)[0] as int?;
  }
}
```

and in line `public override int? Read<int>()` I have errors:

> CS1001: Identifier expected
> CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected
> CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022

When I use Int32 instead int, everything works ok, and it almost resolve my problem, but type float (which is necessary for me) doesn't have Float representation.

I have no ideas for solving this problem anymore. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: It's because of struct. Try changing it to class or object.

Comment: Is there any reason you made the `Read` and `Write` methods generic instead of the `IRegister` interface? Also, I think that `System.Single` is to `float` as `System.Int32` is to `int`.

Comment: Yeah, this is basically a result of not understanding how generic methods work.  +1 to everything Joshua said.  My answer (to a Java question) elaborates on a very similar scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433279/is-it-possible-to-have-an-interface-method-defined-with-a-generic-return-type-an/7433320#7433320  Long story short, the type arguments to generic methods are provided by the _caller_ and not a method override.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson please note that `Int32` mentioned in the question **is not** `System.Int32`, it is **just** `Int32` - a generic type for the method. Indeed conventionally one would use `T` as name or prefix (like `TInt32`), but compiler does not care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try changing the interface to being generic, that way the generic type references are constrained to being of the *same* type, and not just arbitrarily *any* type:

```
public interface IRegister<T> 
    where T : struct
{
    Nullable<T> Read();
    void Write(T value);
}

public abstract class AbstractRegister<T> : IRegister<T>
    where T : struct
{
    protected ModbusClient client;
    protected int Address;
    public abstract Nullable<T> Read();
    public virtual void Write(T value)
    {
        return;
    }
    public AbstractRegister(int address, ModbusClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.Address = address;
    }
}

class InputRegister_int : AbstractRegister<int>
{
    public InputRegister_int(int address, ModbusClient client) : base(address, client) { }

    public override int? Read()
    {
        if (client == null)
          return null;
          return this.client.ReadInputRegisters(this.Address, 1)[0] as int?;
    }
}

class InputRegister_float : AbstractRegister<float>
{
    public InputRegister_float(int address, ModbusClient client) : base(address, client) { }

    public override float? Read()
    {
        if (client == null)
          return null;
          return this.client.ReadInputRegisters(this.Address, 1)[0] as float?;
    }
}
```

The functional difference here is that specifying the *generic type* at the class level, all of the T's in the base class MUST be the same so for `InputRegister_int` all the T's a re now `int`.

From a syntax perspective, notice that the methods DO NOT have the  suffix on their prototypes, this is because they are not generic methods at all, they are specifically typed to the same *type parameter* that was specified when the instance was created.

If you did have a method like this:

```
Nullable<T> Read<T>() where T: struct;
```

Then even to the `InputRegister_int` class we could pass through *ANY* type of struct to that method and expect it to return the value, the following would be expected to be valid at runtime:

```
var intRegister = new InputRegister_int();
int intValue = intRegister.Read<int>();
DateTime dtValue = intRegister.Read<DateTime>();
```

If you really do want your register to be *any* arbitrary type, then we don't really need an *abstract* register at all:

```
public class GenericRegister : IRegister
{
    protected ModbusClient client;
    protected int Address;
    public virtual Nullable<T> Read<T>() where T : struct
    {
        if (client == null)
            return null;
            return this.client.ReadInputRegisters(this.Address, 1)[0] as T?;        
    }
    public virtual void Write<T>(T value) where T : struct
    {
        // TODO: implement generic write logic
        return;
    }
    public AbstractRegister(int address, ModbusClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.Address = address;
    }
}
```

However this leads to a very lazy implementation, the types of the values in your ModBus registers are not going to change, most are fixed to hardware implementations but the internal logic in the PLC will contrain the types for you. Your fixed type `InputRegister_int` allows you do to specific value and type checking on the response from the client when you need to and it helps guide the developers to make reasonable decisions later.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is specifically about "Int32" vs. `int` part of the question.

`Int32` used in the code as example of "this works" is not actually `System.Int32` (which is exactly what `int` is) but rather just a name that *happen to match* name of some system type.

Code below shows simpler example of this - you can see that "Int32" behaves exactly as any other string that is not a type name.

```
using System;
public class SomeClass {

    // exactly the same as T X<T>(), just using `Int32` as type parameter name
    Int32 X<Int32>() { return default(Int32); } 
    
    // fails to compile as `System.Int32` and `int` are concrete types
    System.Int32 Y<System.Int32>() { return default(System.Int32); } 
    int X<int>() { return default(int); } 
}
```

Conventionally name of the type parameter in generic method starts with `T` (just `T` or prefixed with it - `TResult`), but there is rule in C# specification that enforces that. As result anything that is not existing type name is considered "name of the type parameter" as long as it is used in the right place `void M<AnythingThatIsNotType>(...)` .