# c# generic type why can't implement with value type?

Tags: c#

I'm using c#

interface

```
public interface IDataService
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>();
}
```

and

implement class

```
public class ImpleDataService : IDataService
{
    IEnumerable<int> IDataService.GetList<int>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then I got error CS0539 : explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface

but below code is OK

```
    IEnumerable<Int64> IDataService.GetList<Int64>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I don't understand why~?

Comment: You are supposed to implement `GetList<T>`, not `GetList<int>`.

Comment: Did you intend to define `IDataService<T>` and `ImpleDataService : IDataService<int>` ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman fortunately both that suggestion and explanation why `Int64` "works" is covered in [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71118358/generic-method-difference-between-int32-and-int) I picked (which can be considered gold-hammer abuse and self-promotion... but ohhh...well).

Comment: Right, because `GetList<T>`, `GetList<MyTypeParameterName>` and `GetList<Int64>` are equivalent since `Int64` isn't detected as the name of an existing type.